# Linear transformation with no real eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ a linear transformation with no real eigenvalue. The question is to prove that for some basis of $\Bbb R^2$ the matrix of $f$ has the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&-\beta\\
\beta&\alpha\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ and $\beta\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. I don'tknow how begin the answer, I tried with characteristic polynomial of $f$ which is a quadratic polynomial $x^2+bx+c$ with negative discriminant but no success. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are we allowed to use complex eigenvalues here?

Comment: Yes if we need it.

Comment: The usual proof goes like this: diagonalize $f$ with respect to its conjugate complex roots, then find a similarity that brings the diagonal matrix to the desired form.

Comment: What do you mean by similarity? Do you mean a change matrix? How we can find it?

Comment: Yes, a "change matrix", I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, we note that $f$ has the complex eigenvalues $\alpha \pm \beta i$.

Take $g = f - \alpha \,I$ (where $I$ denotes the identity transformation).  It now suffices to find a basis such that the matrix of $g$ has the form
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&-\beta\\\beta & 0}
$$
Note that $g$ has characteristic polynomial $x^2 + \beta^2$.  Thus, we have $g^2  = - \beta^2 I$, by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.  Select any non-zero $x_1 \in \Bbb R^2$ to be the first element of our basis.  Take $x_2 = \frac 1 \beta g(x_1)$ to be the second element of our basis.  We find that
$$
g(x_1) = \beta x_2\\
g(x_2) = g \left( \frac 1 \beta  g(x_1)\right) = \frac{g^2(x_1)}{\beta} = \frac{-\beta^2 x_1}{\beta} = -\beta x_1
$$
Thus, we indeed find that the matrix of $g$ with respect to $\{x_1,x_2\}$ is $M$.  Thus, the matrix of $f = g + \alpha I$ is
$$
M + \alpha I = \pmatrix{0&-\beta\\\beta & 0} + \alpha \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} = \pmatrix{\alpha& - \beta \\ \beta & \alpha}
$$

---

Note: rather than characterizing $\alpha,\beta$ as the complex eigenvalues of $f$, we could say that $\alpha = \frac 12 Tr(f)$, and $\beta$ is such that $(f - \alpha I)^2 = - \beta^2 I$.

Or, note that any quadratic with negative descriminant can be rewritten by completing the square to give
$$
x^2 + bx + c = (x-\alpha)^2 - \beta^2
$$

Comment: Note: this is not the "usual proof" I describe in my comments above. I like this one better, though.

Comment: I think there is a typo in $g=f-2\alpha I$. Anyway, nice proof! Thanks+1.

Comment: I had just caught it, too.  You're welcome.  If you want a reference for the "usual proof", most of the standard linear algebra texts will have it.  Lay's "Linear Algebra and Applications" comes to mind.